# Artifactory incremental backup contains items modified months prior to our last weekly backup

Tags: backup, artifactory

We purged our backup directory after executing serious cleanup of dead docker images in our artifactory hosts registry.  The weekly backup executed without a problem but the next incremental filled the disk.  Looking at the docker images within the incremental backup, I see images from at least 4 months ago.

Can someone explain this behavior or am I like Vizzini from the Princess Bride and I don't understand that word.  Inconceivable.

Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to change the feeling of inconceivable (I like this movie too... :) )

So, Artifactory backup works as follow:

1. Incremental - The first time that it will run will run as a full backup and will backup everything. The second time (and on) it will run it will only change the diffs between the backup folder to the actual stat in Artifactory.
2. Full backup with retention - Let's say that you have set the retention to 168 hours (a week), that means that upon running a backup, Artifactory will check if the last backup finished 168 hours ago AND if it had no errors while running. The "AND" part here is very important. If you had an error message in the backup the retention will not delete the previous backups so you won't have a state of missing data.

I would check the backup logs to make sure that you don't see any issues in it and if so resolve the errors, it should fix the retention issue.

Hope this helps to make this topic conceivable :)

Comment: Ok, so I was trying to use a non incremental to see the incremental but used different directories... hence my problem then.  Ok, let em experiment./ . Thanks